# How whisper messages being routed in Ethereum Network?

Tags: nodes, whisper, devp2p, message

Does the Whisper messages are broadcasted to all Ethereum nodes? or is there any internal routing, if yes how?

Answer (score 1):

Whisper messages are broadcasts to all nodes, but not all the nodes are necessarily configured to act on them. Have you read the white paper -
 https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Whisper-PoC-2-Protocol-Spec